# Hide InlineKeyboardMarkup in no answer provided

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to hide a InlineKeyboardMarkup if no answer is provided. I'm using Python and python-telegram-bot. Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: can you please describe better the scenario? what do you mean with no answer provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit the message sent without providing a reply_markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can send [editMessageReplyMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup) without `reply_markup` parament.

<del>As I know, there is no method can remove keyboard without sending messages, but you can send a simple message with [ReplyKeyboardRemove](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove) and delete message via [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) method immediately.</del>

Comment: In this case it is not a ReplyKeyboard, it is an InlineKeyboard. I guess I can't use such an API method with an InlineKeyboard.

Comment: @Irene Sorry about I missed `Inline`, I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help, I finally chose a not really beautiful but simple solution, just edit the message sent.